# How to prevent vscode as default program to run html file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I double click a html file, it will be automatically opened in vscode. I set Firefox as default program and it works fine, but every time after I reboot, `Visual Stadio Code - URL Handler` still be the default program to open a html file.

I use linux mint 18.3, it only happens after vscode upgrade to 1.28

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file in the chosen format and choose *Open With... -> Other Application* or *Open With Other Application*.

Don't forget to check the *Remember this application for "..." files* checkbox to apply your selection for all files of the same format.

[As discussed here](https://www.faqforge.com/linux/change-default-application-to-open-files-linux-mint)